# using variables in groovy context.expand expression

Tags: groovy, expand

I tried to automate a test case using groovy script and soapUI.

Sending a soap request, I got a response contains a company list.
What I'ld like to do is verifying names of listed companies.
Size of the response array is not fixed.

So I tried the script below just for the beginning but I got stuck..

```
def count = context.expand( '${Properties#count}' )
count = count.toInteger()
def i = 0
while (i<count)
    (
def response = context.expand( '${getCompanyList#Response#//multiRef['+i+']/@id}' )
 log.info(response)
i=İ+1   
    )
```

I get

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script12.groovy: 6: unexpected token: def @ line 6, column 1. def response = context.expand( '${getCompanyList#Response#//multiRef['+i+']/@id}' ) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: def @ line 6, column 1. at
```

I should somehow put "i" in the "response" definition..

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong characters to in your while statement, it should be braces (`{}`), not parentheses (`()`).

This is why the error is regarding the **`def`** on line 6, and has nothing to do with the `i` variable.

You also have `İ` in your example, which is not a valid variable name in Groovy.

I think you wanted this:

```
def count = context.expand( '${Properties#count}' )
count = count.toInteger()
def i = 0
while (i<count) {
    def response = context.expand( '${getCompanyList#Response#//multiRef['+i+']/@id}' )
    log.info(response)
    i=i+1   
}
```

However, this being Groovy, you can do this much cleaner using:

```
def count = context.expand( '${Properties#count}' )
count.toInteger().times { i ->
    def response = context.expand( '${getCompanyList#Response#//multiRef['+i+']/@id}' )
    log.info(response)
}
```

(And if you replace `i` inside the closure with `it`, you can remove the `i ->` as well.)